# Keep Graphical Outline when Screen Size Changes

Tags: iphone, xcode, storyboard, alignment, viewcontroller

Beginner...

I suppose somewhat related to the question below, I would like the view controller to appear the same on each device with only the size of the graphics changed, ([storyboard iPhone 8 vs iPhone 4s](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nshse.png))

I've tried my best to read about and understand the Constraints, but with no luck. I add a constraint, then click away from the "Add New Constraints", and when I select the object again to view constraints it appears as if nothing is set anymore, ([Constraints added](https://i.stack.imgur.com/spHqP.png) & [Constraints gone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/akNVF.png))

Even if they are sill there, but this isn't how you see them, the image still moves when I check the storyboards or the simulators of two different sized devices.

Any recommendations on how to fix either issue or just somewhere else to look for answers would be well received!

---

I would like to automatically align all the graphics I've placed in the "View Controller", ([Unaligned Storyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qo2yF.png)),
and have those graphics resize themselves to maintain their placement when loaded onto a device with a different size screen, ([Main Storyboard of two devices](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jXwaZ.png))

I've decided I want *most* of the graphics to only be in the center of the controller.

EDIT
*this has been solved*
I've discovered how to align the graphics as I desire by clicking the [Align "Horizontally in Container"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YFk8y.png) 
I'm not sure how or why I didn't see this sooner.

Unfortunately, the graphics still become distorted when on a different sized screen.

Answer (score 0):

I've discovered how to align the graphics as I desire by clicking the [Align "Horizontally in Container"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J2SOp.png) 
I'm not sure how or why I didn't see this sooner.

Unfortunately, the graphics still become distorted when on a different sized screen.